# `watch jobs` doesn't work in linux

Tags: linux, csh

I want to use `watch jobs` to see an updated showing of all the jobs I have running, but when I try to do it, all I get is the headline of watch and a blank screen. But using the script

```
while (1)
  sleep 10;
  clear;
  jobs;
end
```

does work, where is the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Job control is managed by the shell and `jobs` is a shell builtin function.  If you use the command `which jobs` you will see there is no binary called jobs anywhere in your $PATH.

`watch` is doing a system call every two seconds so shell functions aren't available to it.

You could also try `watch 'ps awwwux | grep yourusername'`.  But its not quite the same as `jobs`.

Comment: ps awwwux | grep <username> shows too much stuff for me (I use google chrome which has plenty of threads), so I prefer using `pgrep -fl <some regex>` here

Answer (score 4):

Job is not a system command its a shell command - when you start watch he executes a subshell which has its own job managment and of course no jobs. Try watch ps.